# Create a Visual Studio IP DHCP generator

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to know if its possible to do on Visual Studio a "Form" DHCP generator.
For example:
Write an IP address: 192.168.1.1
Write PC's: 5
Click here, generate DHCP!
192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4, 192.168.1.5.
I have this doubt because i think its easy doing arithmetic calculation, but, "IP" addresses you can not calculate adding 1 plus 1.
How can I do?

Comment: You have to go do it. What problem are you having?

Comment: this is not a problem, I only want to do an IP DHCP generator on Visual Studio

Comment: Go right ahead. You get started, and if you have any problems, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Split` you can spilit up 192.168.1.1 into ["192", "168", "1", "1"] and then you would just have to cast it and then do `castedArray[3]++;`

Comment: I will try to split my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Visual Studio project that prints a series of possible DHCP/IP addresses. But that isn't all it takes for a true DHCP server.

No, ip addresses aren't incremented by just 1 to 999. But they are in sets of of octets, with a maximum of 255. So your application would have to be smart enough to increment the first octet up to 255, then increment the 3rd octet in the series appropriately, up to 255.

Comment: Im trying to do a dhcp provider simulation, thats all. And I know, the IP address is set in 4 octects with maximum of 255.